# Stop Javascript from conflicting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I am using this javascript code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var speed = 'slow';

$('html, body').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
$('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
    $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
            window.location = url;
        });
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

What this code does is fade in the page on the site for every link that is clicked. My problem is that I have a html5 music play that is written like this.

```
<ul class="graphic">
<li><a href="MP3 URL HERE">TITLE OF SONG HERE</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is an inline player. When you click the lay button or the title it's suppose to play on the same page. But I realize that the code above opens the link to the mp3 in the same window instead of playing it on the same page.

Is there anyway I can get the code above to not conflict with anything on a certain page or in a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `data-music-link` attribute on your music links and change the code to ignore these.

`$('a[href]:not([data-music-link]), button[href]:not([data-music-link])').click(...)`

or

```
$('a[href], button[href]')
    .filter(function () { return !$(this).is('[data-music-link]'); })
    .click(...)
```

You could also use a similar strategy, but ignore links ending by well-know media extensions such as `mp3`.

Finally, rather than adding a listener on every single link, you should rather use an [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to add the above code for the javascript file...but as far as for the music is this what you meant '<a href="MP3 URL HERE" class="data-music-link">TITLE OF SONG HERE</a>' @plalx

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="MP3 URL HERE" data-music-link="MP3 URL HERE">TITLE OF SONG HERE</a>
```

you can manipulate the **data-music-link** in your jQuery instead **href** attribute.